# PnP Core .Net Access subfolder inside my Documents Folder in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, pnp-js, pnp-core-sdk

Currently implementing Code to Access a specific Folder called "Customer" which is inside my Documents Folder in Sharepoint. Whatever I tried it wont work..

```
var list = await pnpContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Documents",
   p => p.RootFolder,
   p => p.Items.QueryProperties(p => p.UniqueId, p => p.All, p => p.Title),
   p => p.Fields);
var folder = list.Items.AsRequested().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title == "Customer");
```

The result of this is that I always get a "null".
Hope anyone have ideas to fix it.

Edit:
Also tried "GetFolderByServerRelativeUrlAsync" still failed.

```
string folderUrl = $"{pnpContext.Uri.PathAndQuery}/Documents/Customer";
var folder = await pnpContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrlAsync(folderUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
IList list = await _pnpContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Documents");
var subfolder = await list.RootFolder.Folders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Title == "Customer");
```